# CalendarContract.Events._ID is missing in Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-calendar, calendarcontract

My app queries a particular event in `CalendarContract.Events` using `Events._ID`. This worked well until attempting to run it on a 5.0 device, now I get an exception

```
01-12 17:28:50.525: E/Unknown Source(18499): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
    no such column: CalendarContract.Events._ID (code 1): ,
    while compiling:
        SELECT _id, account_type, title, organizer, description, eventLocation,
            hasAlarm, calendar_id
        FROM view_events
        WHERE (lastSynced = 0 AND (CalendarContract.Events._ID=1))
```

Querying all columns in `Events` indeed does not return `_ID`. Any idea why this has been removed or if it's a bug? I can't seem to find away to uniquely identify events any more.

Here is my query:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{Events._ID, Events.ACCOUNT_TYPE, Events.TITLE,
        Events.ORGANIZER, Events.DESCRIPTION, Events.EVENT_LOCATION, Events.HAS_ALARM,
        Events.CALENDAR_ID};

Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(EVENTS_CONTENT_URI, projection,
         "CalendarContract.Events._ID=" + eventId, null, null);
```

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Are you sure it should be `_ID` and not `_id`?

Comment: Afraid not, I get the same "no such column" exception when I try with _id @ianhanniballake

Comment: See my answer, it will work as expected with a vaid ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of @Andrew isn't right.
You are wrongly using the `selectionClause` and the `selectionArgs` parameters.

Here is what you are doing:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(EVENTS_CONTENT_URI, projection,
    CalendarContract.Events._ID + "=" + eventId, null, null);
```

And here is what you should do:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(EVENTS_CONTENT_URI, projection,
    CalendarContract.Events._ID + " = ?", new String[]{eventId}, null);
```

The eventId needs to be passed within the `selectionArgs` so that the contentResolver can build the query statement for you, chaining the `selectionArgs` and substituting them to the ? char in the `selectionClause` parameter.

The question is three years old, but I hope my answer can help someone else.

Comment: Wow, thank you, that fixed it! What's weird is it worked on previous Android versions with the old query. The question is a few months old, not three years ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad it helped you :) Maybe on older Android versions there was a bug, I've always been using selectionClause and selectionArgs this way. See ya!